# Incremental counting and saving all values in one string

Tags: c#, string, increment

I'm having trouble thinking of a logical way to achieve this. I have a method which sends a web request with a for loop that is counting up from 1 to x, the request counts up until it finds a specific response and then sends the URL + number to another method.

After this, saying we got the number 5, I need to create a string which displays as "1,2,3,4,5" but cannot seem to find a way to create the entire string, everything I try is simply replacing the string and only keeping the last number.

```
string unionMod = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            unionMod =+ count + ",";
        }
```

I assumed I'd be able to simply add each value onto the end of the string but the output is just "5," with it being the last number. I have looked around but I can't seem to even think of what I would search in order to get the answer, I have a hard-coded solution but ideally, I'd like to not have a 30+ string with each possible value and just have it created when needed.

Any pointers?

P.S: Any coding examples are appreciated but I've probably just forgotten something obvious so any directions you can give are much appreciated, I should sleep but I'm on one of those all-night coding grinds.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use `+=` instead of `=+`

Comment: Change `=+` to `+=`..

Comment: Or even better, use a `StringBuilder`, since using `+=` in a possibly long loop is definetely inefficient.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```unionMod += i + ",";```?

Comment: Yup, thank you guys. I did try this but had an error, it must of been an unrelated error, what a waste of a good hour trying to figure out a solution for a simple typo.

Comment: You could always try: `string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, 5))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's been pointed out, you should use `+=` instead of `=+`. The latter means "take count and append a comma to it", which is the incorrect result you experienced.

You could also simplify your code like this:

```
int count = 10;
string unionMod = String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, count));
```

`Enumerable.Range` generates a sequence of integers between its two parameters and `String.Join` joins them up with the given separator character.

Comment: Ah brilliant, thank you for the code. a much preferred solution to stringbuilder.

Comment: This is a good solution, but my preference is to go one step further:  `public static string CommaSeparated<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) => string.Join(",", items);`  And now your solution is `Enumerable.Range(1, count).CommaSeparated()`, which is very readable.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your problem is the `+=`. You should avoid concatenating strings because it allocates a new string. Instead you should use a StringBuilder.

Your Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/qQIqWx

My Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/sx7cxq

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var counter = 5;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(var i = 1; i <= counter; ++i) {
            sb.Append(i);

            if (i != counter) {
               sb.Append(",");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }
```

Comment: I feel extremely stupid, I tried this but it threw an error so I assumed it was the other way around, must of been an error located somewhere else. Than you for the help.

a 4 year degree did not prepare me for 26 hours of no sleep and long coding sessions.

Comment: I am glad to help! post increment and pre increment can be tricky sometimes specially without sleep.